# Python. Sending a signal from a Worker

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working in a Python application, using PySide on a Raspberry Pi, with Raspbian Jessie OS.

I'm very new in Python, and I'm not an expert at all. So probably it's a begginer's question.

In my application, I have:

- main thread      -> Gui Thread that implements front end.
- subyacent thread -> Makes some long work (no gui at all, plain code), 
                     implemented in a Custom class named MyWorker .

In some places of subyacent thread's code, I need to emit a signal that have to be catched by the main thread. In a previous version, I did it this way:

## Main thread's code

```
    #Slot for clicked button
    def Slot_Start_Calculation (self):

        self.MyLongThread = QThread()
        MyLongWorker = MyWorker(self, Qty)
        MyLongWorker.moveToThread(self.MyLongThread)

        self.MyLongThread.started.connect(MyLongWorker.Run_LongWorker)
        MyLongWorker.WorkerFinished.connect(self.MyLongThread.quit)
        MyLongWorker.WorkerFinished.connect(self.MyLongWorker.deleteLater)
        MyLongThread.finished.connect(self.MyLongThread.deleteLater)

        MyLongThread.start()


    def Slot_Worker_Sent_A_Signal (self, Result):

        print ("Worker sent this result: " + str(Result))
        .
        .
        .
```

## MyWorker's code

```
class MyWorker(QObject):

    WorkerFinished = Signal()
    CustomSignal = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent, Quantity)

        super().__init__(parent)
        self_parent = parent
        self.Quantity = Quantity
        print("Myworker's constructor")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Myworker's destructor")


    def Run_LongWorker (self):

        self.CustomSignal.connect(self.parent.Slot_Worker_Sent_A_Signal)
        .
        .
        .
        self.CustomSignal.emit(MyPartialResult)
        .
        .
        .
        self.WorkerFinished.emit()
```

This code is running in a test environment from some weeks ago while I finish some details of the GUI, and I didn't see anything wrong.
Yesterday searching in the web I casually noticed that QObject::moveToThread can't move objects with a parent

https:[//forum.qt.io/topic/40653/qobject-movetothread-cannot-move-objects-with-a-parent][1]

so I'm afraid that my code may have problems that I have not yet detected.

I modified this part of code, and now it is:

## New code for main Thread

```
    #New slot for clicked button.
    def Slot_Start_Calculation (self):

        MyLongThread = QThread()
        MyLongWorker = MyWorker(Qty)
        MyLongWorker.moveToThread(MyLongThread)

        MyLongThread.started.connect(MyLongWorker.Run_LongWorker)
        MyLongWorker.WorkerFinished.connect(MyLongThread.quit)
        MyLongWorker.WorkerFinished.connect(MyLongWorker.deleteLater)
        MyLongThread.finished.connect(MyLongThread.deleteLater)

        MyLongThread.start()


    def Slot_Worker_Sent_A_Signal (self, Result):

        print ("Worker sent this result: " + str(Result))
        .
        .
        .
```

## New code for MyWorker

```
class MyWorker(QObject):

    WorkerFinished = Signal()
    CustomSignal = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, Quantity)

        super().__init__()
        self.Quantity = Quantity
        print("Myworker's constructor")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Myworker's destructor")

    def Run_LongWorker (self):

        self.CustomSignal.connect( ??? .Slot_Worker_Sends_A_Signal)
        .
        .
        .
        self.CustomSignal.emit(MyPartialResult)
        .
        .
        .
        self.WorkerFinished.emit()
```

So, now, I don't really know how to connect this signal to a slot that lives in main thread, cause if I'm not wrong, there is no parent/children relation since I changed thread affinity.

Could someone please tell me if there is a way to do this, and guide me towards documentation about this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think I found an answer. In constructor of the Worker class, I had to change the parent object reference and the super class init calling.

```
class MyWorker(QObject):

    WorkerFinished = Signal()
    CustomSignal = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent = None, Quantity)
        super().__init__()
        self.Quantity = Quantity
        print("Myworker's constructor")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Myworker's destructor")


    def Run_LongWorker (self):

        .
        .
        .
        self.CustomSignal.emit(MyPartialResult)
        .
        .
        .
        self.WorkerFinished.emit()
```

And now everything is working as expected.

If somebody sees a problem with that code, please feel free to tell me.

Thanks!